# Do all expansions have to be bought in pairs to maintain playability for 3-4 players?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

I've read that Arkham Horror the Card Game can support 3-4 players if you purchase an additional copy, but does this mean that to continue to play with 3-4 players, every expansion would need to be purchased twice (including the mythos packs as well)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. Post the core-set, expansions will be divided into scenario/encounter cards, and player cards. You only need one set of the scenario/encounter cards per play group; however, the expansions will only come with 1 playset of each player card.

So, if a new player card comes out and you and your friend both want to run a full playset of it, you'll need two copies of the expansion. But if you can play around that, you only need one.